# start chromium on startup using systemd

Tags: systemd, xorg, chrome

I am having trouble to start chromium within openbox within xorg on startup, using systemd.

I have a script that starts everything:

```
#/opt/kiosk.sh
#!/bin/bash

xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11

chromium-browser --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'
```

typing (as root):

```
sudo -u kioskuser startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sk --
```

starts the browser just as it should be.

How can I accomplish this via `systemd`

Right now I have:

```
 #/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service

 [Unit]
 After=systemd-user-sessions.service

 [Service]
 User=kioskuser
 StartExec=/bin/bash -c 'startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sk --'

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it does not work. Any Ideas?

Here the resulting error:

[image]

Comment: There is a typo here: `systemmd-user-sessions.service`. If that is the actual file, fix that for starters!

Comment: true! changed it!

Comment: Good. If it still doesn't work, edit the question and add relevant error messages.

Comment: check! Errors added…

Comment: Great. I do not have the answer I'm afraid, but I upvoted the question since you now make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/

Comment: It would be much nicer if you posted the full error log and not just last 5 lines of it (and not as an image, to that end).

Answer (score 1):

I missed to install `xserver-xorg-legacy` and to put:

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf`.